# R: Simplifying code to convert letter grades to numeric grades

Tags: r

I have written a function in R that will convert a data frame containing letter grades into numeric grades. I then use sapply() on each column of the data frame. Is there a simpler way to do this that doesn't require three separate calls of sapply? Is there a way to apply a function to every element of a data frame instead of every row or column?

The source data, "grades", looks like this:

```
grades <- read.table("Grades.txt", header = TRUE)
head(grades)
  final_exam quiz_avg homework_avg
1          C        A            A
2         C-       B-            A
3         D+       B+            A
4         B+       B+            A
5          F       B+            A
6          B       A-            A
```

My "`convert_grades`" function looks like this:

```
convert_grades <- function(x) {
    if (x == "A+") {
        x <- 4.3
    } else if (x == "A") {
        x <- 4
    } else if (x == "A-") {
        x <- 3.7
    } else if (x == "B+") {
        x <- 3.3
    } else if (x == "B") {
        x <- 3
    } else if (x == "B-") {
        x <- 2.7
    } else if (x == "C+") {
        x <- 2.3
    } else if (x == "C") {
        x <- 2
    } else if (x == "C-") {
        x <- 1.7
    } else if (x == "D+") {
        x <- 1.3
    } else if (x == "D") {
        x <- 1
    } else if (x == "D-") {
        x <- 0.7
    } else if (x == "F") {
        x <- 0
    } else {
        x <- NA
    }
    return(x)
}
```

My current approach is as follows:

```
num_grades <- grades
num_grades[, 1] <- sapply(grades[, 1], convert_grades)
num_grades[, 2] <- sapply(grades[, 2], convert_grades)
num_grades[, 3] <- sapply(grades[, 3], convert_grades)

head(num_grades)
   final_exam quiz_avg homework_avg
 1        2.0      4.0            4
 2        1.7      2.7            4
 3        1.3      3.3            4
 4        3.3      3.3            4
 5        0.0      3.3            4
 6        3.0      3.7            4
```

Comment: JK,  but surprised nobody suggested sorting the results of `utf8ToInt(grades)`   :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would rewrite your `convert_grades` function as follows:

```
convert_grades <- function(x) {
  A <- factor(x, levels=c("A+", "A", "A-",
                     "B+", "B", "B-",
                     "C+", "C", "C-",
                     "D+", "D", "D-", "F"))
  values <- c(4.3, 4, 3.7, 
              3.3, 3, 2.7,
              2.3, 2, 1.7,
              1.3, 1, 0.7, 0)
  values[A]
}
```

Then, I would do the conversion like this:

```
num_grades <- grades
num_grades[] <- lapply(num_grades, convert_grades)
num_grades
  final_exam quiz_avg homework_avg
1        2.0      4.0            4
2        1.7      2.7            4
3        1.3      3.3            4
4        3.3      3.3            4
5        0.0      3.3            4
6        3.0      3.7            4
```

Comment: You can also write `convert_grades <-  Compose(as.character, Curry('[', grvec))` using package `functional` and the `grvec` from Ben's answer.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, I've seen (but never used) that function. Thanks for providing an example.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, do you need to worry about converting to character? (I haven't tried it ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Yes you do.  Otherwise `[` will coerce to numeric, giving the wrong results.

Answer (score 11):

First vectorize your function: you could do this with `ifelse`, or:

```
grvec <- c("A+"=4.3,"A"=4,"A-"=3.7,"B+"=3.3,"B"=3,"B-"=2.7,
           "C+"=2.3,"C"=2,"C-"=1.7,"D+"=1.3,"D"=1,"D-"= 0.7,
       "F"=0)

grades <- data.frame(final_exam=c("C","C-","D+"),
                     quiz_avg=c("A","B-","Q"))

##   final_exam quiz_avg
## 1          C        A
## 2         C-       B-
## 3         D+        Q

num_grades <- apply(grades,2,function(x) grvec[as.character(x)])
##      final_exam quiz_avg
## [1,]        2.0      4.0
## [2,]        1.7      2.7
## [3,]        1.3       NA
```

Comment: This will be much faster than using `apply`: `num_grades <- grades; num_grades[] <- lapply(num_grades, function(x) grvec[as.character(x)])`, but +1 nonetheless. It will probably even be faster than my approach.

Comment: I like the result from `sapply(grades, ...)` except for the row names.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty fast hash approach that shines the more grades you have:

```
library(qdap)

grvec <- list("A+"=4.3,"A"=4,"A-"=3.7,"B+"=3.3,"B"=3,"B-"=2.7,
    "C+"=2.3,"C"=2,"C-"=1.7,"D+"=1.3,"D"=1,"D-"= 0.7, "F"=0)

dat[] <- lapply(dat, lookup, list2df(grvec)[, c(2:1)])

##   final_exam quiz_avg homework_avg
## 1        2.0      4.0            4
## 2        1.7      2.7            4
## 3        1.3      3.3            4
## 4        3.3      3.3            4
## 5        0.0      3.3            4
## 6        3.0      3.7            4
```

Comment: I think you mean "grades" instead of "dat".